# Shapekey range animates in viewport but not in render

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

I have a mesh with two shape keys (*Basis* and *Key*). I keyframed the value of *Key* from 0 to 1 and back to 0, and added a cyclic modifier to its f-curve, so that the mesh continuously "pulses" between *Basis* and *Key*. Then I add keyframes to *Key*'s Range Max, to control how much the *Key* shape influences the mesh at different times.

When playing the animation in the 3d Viewport or rendering a still, everything behave as expected, but when rendering the animation, the keyframed Range Max is discarded. If I start rendering whilst the playhead is on a frame where Range Max = 1, it stays at 1 for the whole animation and it stays at 0 if I start rendering from a frame where Range Max = 0 (so in this case doesn't animate the shapekey at all).

I've search to see if it's a known bug and didn't find anything. Also saw that cyclic dependencies could be a problem but I don't think that's what's happening here.

Here's a simple test file to illustrate. Compare playing in Viewport, with rendering from frame 1 to 100, with rendering from frame 50 to 100.

[image]

*Edit: looks like a bug so I filed a report [here](https://developer.blender.org/T80166)*

Comment: Hello, I feel like you could achieve the same effect with just the *value* keyframed. Looks like you know how to use fcurves modifiers. Set the After to **No Cycles** in your cycle modifier and you'll achieve the same result. FYI I think your problem comes from the fact that modifying the *Max Range* does not automatically cause an update of the *value*

Comment: hi, thanks but the example is a simplified version. In my actual project the shapekey is on a lattice that makes a character sway to the rhythm of a song for 3 minutes (hence the cycle). At 2 different moments i need the char to stand still for 10s each time. It looks perfect when played in the viewport, with the max range updating the value just fine

Comment: @Gorgious ... and also, the problem is the same when baking the cycled curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://developer.blender.org/T80166) in 2.90 (and 2.8x). It is fixed in 2.91 alpha